# Characters of tori in finite reductive group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected split reductive group over a finite field $k$. Suppose $G$ has connected centre. Let $T$ be a maximal split torus with Weyl group $W$. Note that $W$ acts on the finite group $T(k)$; thus, it acts on characters of $T(k)$.

Let $\theta: T(k) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ be a $W$-invariant character.

Question: Does $\theta$ extend to a character of $G(k)$?

Comment: Isn't the order $2$ character of the split torus of $SL_2(\mathbb F_p)$ a counterexample?

Comment: But the centre of SL_2 is disconnected (in characteristic not equal to 2).

Comment: What about $\textbf{PGL}_2$, then?

Comment: I think the order 2 character of maximal torus of PGL_2 actually extends to all of PGL_2(k). (Note abelianization of PGL_2(k) is nontrivial)

Comment: @Dr.Evil, indeed, for $p \ne 2$ (otherwise there is no non-trivial character!) the [desired](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424378/characters-of-tori-in-finite-reductive-group#comment1090879_424378) extension is $g \mapsto \operatorname{sgn}_k(\det(g))$.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit.** The answer below is incorrect.  The correct computation is the determinant of the Cartan matrix, which happens to equal $1$ for $E_8$.

I believe the answer is "no" for $G$ equal to the split form of $E_8$ over a finite field $k$ of odd characteristic.  The set of rational points is a simple finite group.  The center of $E_8$ is trivial.  For a maximal split torus $T$, I believe the action of the Weyl group $W$ on $T(k)/(T(k))^2$ is trivial, since $W$ is generated by simple reflections arising from copies of $\textbf{SL}_2$ in the group (the "root groups"), and the action of the Weyl group is trivial for $\textbf{SL}_2$.  So this would mean that every nontrivial character of $T(k)/(T(k))^2$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not following the argument that $W$ acts trivially $T(k)/(T(k))^2$. I would appreciate more details.